# Use vb.net delete access mdb file

Tags: vb.net

I have a single user program using oledb to connect a mdb file, before it connect, i need to check the mdb exist.if exist, delete and create . if not exist, just create. but when I check the mdb exist and want to delete, the ldb file  lock, I want to ask can I force to unlock the ldb and delete the mdb file？？

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OleDb, you *must* close or dispose all `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand` objects used.¹ Otherwise, the mdb file is still "in use" and cannot be removed.

An easy way to do this is to wrap all such objects in `Using` blocks.

For example, instead of

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection(...)
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(...)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

you would write:

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection(...)
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(...)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

(Note that you do not need to explicitly `Close` the connection any more, this is done automatically at the end of the `Using` block.)

---

¹ This is different than, for example, `SqlCommand`s, which react more gracefully to not being disposed. As a general rule, however: If it implements `IDisposable`, dispose it.

Comment: Good answer, but I have to ask. How do you do that? I mean the footer note (1.)

Comment: Win+R/charmap/Enter/Double-click the superscript 1 (middle-right)/Click "Copy"/Paste into Stack-Overflow posting.